# In-place insert characters into string at given positions in linear time

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, boost, data-structures

I have a `std::string` and a sequence of `int`s. I would like to add characters *before* the positions indicated by the `int`s. This operation should be performed *in-place*. As an example consider:

```
string: "abcde"
positions: 1, 3
character to be inserted: ' '
=> string after modification: "a bc de"
```

Algorithmwise, it is no problem to implement this in O(n) time, but I suspect that this already implemented somewhere in e.g. boost. However, I could not find an implementation there. Is there a C++ library offering this functionality?

Comment: What about: `std::string::insert()`? Just iterate positions and add any character you want.

Comment: @DimChtz that will do unnecessary moving around of characters when called many times, though it would still be O(n)

Comment: Depends on what "linear time" means. Inserting character(s) into the middle of a `std::string` is `O(n)`, with `n` being the string length.  So inserting `X` characters, at different position does not affect the complexity, since its independent of `n`, so it's still `O(n)`. But I suspect that this is not the real intention of this obvious, silly question from some other silly online quiz site is all about; and although the expected answer is not that complicated, stackoverflow.com is not really where one finds someone else to figure out a silly question from some silly online quiz site.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I think this does only hold if `X` is constant (which it is not in my case).

Comment: Strictly speaking, the use of `insert` gives you O(n*m) where n is the string size and m is the number of insertions. The OP is asking for O(n).

Comment: @tobi303 Would it really be O(n)? I think it could degenerate to O(n*n), if the number of insertions is not constant, or am I missing something?

Comment: ...anyhow, there is no method that takes a vector of indices and inserts a charater in that positions of a string, though it is quite straightforward to write one

Comment: `X` doesn't have to be constant. It all depends on how complexity is defined. Complexity is measured against some specified metric. If complexity is based on the size of the string, that's the only thing that matters. Even if complexity is defined as based on the length of the string plus the number of characters to insert, this is still linear complexity, because doubling the sum total (whether it comes at the expense of the string, or the number of chars to insert) still doubles the number of resulting operations. Still linear.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I agree. Moreover, I know how I could implement this function in O(n) time (as written in my description), but I specifically would like to know if I have to implement this algorithm myself or if there is already a library out there coming with it that I could use.

Comment: Right, there is no built-in method that does this already. That's the whole point of that silly question, from some silly online quiz site, that nobody really cares about: to write one yourself. I mean, it makes no sense to ask a question whose answer is simply: call a method whose name is `A`, with parameters `b` and `c`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE** To the updated question that includes the requirement for *in-place* operation:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/57d2de3f5967e4ee)</kbd>**

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
#include <array>

template <typename What>
void multi_insert(std::string& text, std::vector<size_t> positions, What const& insertion) {
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;
    assert(std::is_sorted(positions.begin(), positions.end()));

    auto source_n  = text.length();
    auto extension = insertion.size() * positions.size();

    text.resize(text.length() + extension);

    using Rit     = std::string::reverse_iterator;
    Rit dest_it   = text.rbegin(),
        source_it = dest_it + extension;

    auto posit = positions.rbegin();

    while (dest_it != source_it) {
        assert(*posit <= source_n);

        for (;source_n && *posit != source_n; --source_n)
            *dest_it++ = *source_it++;

        dest_it = std::copy(std::make_reverse_iterator(insertion.end()), std::make_reverse_iterator(insertion.begin()), dest_it);
        ++posit;
    }
}

void multi_insert(std::string& text, std::vector<size_t> positions, char insertion = ' ') {
    multi_insert(text, std::move(positions), std::array<char, 1> {{insertion}});
}

#include <iostream>

static size_t constexpr NONE = -1;

template <typename What>
void do_tests(What const& insertion) {
    std::vector<size_t> p;

    for (size_t a : { NONE, 0ul, 1ul, 2ul, 3ul, 4ul, 5ul })
    for (size_t b : { NONE, 0ul, 1ul, 2ul, 3ul, 4ul, 5ul })
    {
        if (b<a) 
            continue;

        p.assign({a,b});
        p.erase(std::remove_if(p.begin(), p.end(), [](auto n) { return n == NONE; }), p.end());

        std::string text = "abcde";
        multi_insert(text, p, insertion);

        auto opt = [](size_t n) -> char { return n==NONE?'.':('0'+n); };
        std::cout << opt(a) << " " << opt(b) << " Result: '" << text << "'\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    do_tests('!');
    do_tests(std::string("***"));
}
```

Prints

```
. . Result: 'abcde'
0 . Result: '!abcde'
0 0 Result: '!!abcde'
0 1 Result: '!a!bcde'
0 2 Result: '!ab!cde'
0 3 Result: '!abc!de'
0 4 Result: '!abcd!e'
0 5 Result: '!abcde!'
1 . Result: 'a!bcde'
1 1 Result: 'a!!bcde'
1 2 Result: 'a!b!cde'
1 3 Result: 'a!bc!de'
1 4 Result: 'a!bcd!e'
1 5 Result: 'a!bcde!'
2 . Result: 'ab!cde'
2 2 Result: 'ab!!cde'
2 3 Result: 'ab!c!de'
2 4 Result: 'ab!cd!e'
2 5 Result: 'ab!cde!'
3 . Result: 'abc!de'
3 3 Result: 'abc!!de'
3 4 Result: 'abc!d!e'
3 5 Result: 'abc!de!'
4 . Result: 'abcd!e'
4 4 Result: 'abcd!!e'
4 5 Result: 'abcd!e!'
5 . Result: 'abcde!'
5 5 Result: 'abcde!!'
. . Result: 'abcde'
0 . Result: '***abcde'
0 0 Result: '******abcde'
0 1 Result: '***a***bcde'
0 2 Result: '***ab***cde'
0 3 Result: '***abc***de'
0 4 Result: '***abcd***e'
0 5 Result: '***abcde***'
1 . Result: 'a***bcde'
1 1 Result: 'a******bcde'
1 2 Result: 'a***b***cde'
1 3 Result: 'a***bc***de'
1 4 Result: 'a***bcd***e'
1 5 Result: 'a***bcde***'
2 . Result: 'ab***cde'
2 2 Result: 'ab******cde'
2 3 Result: 'ab***c***de'
2 4 Result: 'ab***cd***e'
2 5 Result: 'ab***cde***'
3 . Result: 'abc***de'
3 3 Result: 'abc******de'
3 4 Result: 'abc***d***e'
3 5 Result: 'abc***de***'
4 . Result: 'abcd***e'
4 4 Result: 'abcd******e'
4 5 Result: 'abcd***e***'
5 . Result: 'abcde***'
5 5 Result: 'abcde******'
```

Comment: Added a copying, streaming version (i.e. taking input and output iterators) http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e5dde1d22670080

Comment: Thanks, but isn't the in-place variant quadratic (consider e.g. the situation where you'd want to insert a character before each character in the string)? (No need to update the answer, though; I just would like to make sure that I am not overlooking something.)

Comment: @phimuemue Yes it is.

Comment: @phimuemue I see you added the "inplace" requirement explicitly to the question. You could achieve it by going backwards and calculating the prospective length ahead-of-time. I'll add it in some 2 hours (cooking dinner here)

Comment: Okay. Finally got around to it: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/57d2de3f5967e4ee)** There's room for micro-optimizations, but I wouldn't bother before profiling on your target architecture. This is one of those cases where prefetch can really ruin the - on paper - better algorithmic complexity

Comment: By the way this algo has 2 bonuses: It handles multi-char insertions (generically) and it skips the work if no insertions are left anymore (say, on a 100-char text, if the only insertion position is at 99, only char is actually shifted, if the insertion positions are all at 100, nothing is ever shifted and it's just a simple append). If the `text.capacity()` was sufficiently reserved, there are zero allocations.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a standard implementation that does exactly that, but you could achieve this using:

```
int main() {
  std::string input { "abcde" };
  std::set<size_t> positions { 1, 3 };
  char separator = ' ';

  std::string output;
  output.reserve(input.size() + positions.size()); // Make sure (at most) a single allocation is performed

  unsigned index = 0;
  auto pos = positions.begin();
  for (auto & i : input)
  {
    if (pos != positions.end() && *pos == index)
    {
      output += separator;
      ++pos;
    }

    output += i;
    ++index;
  }

  std::cout << output << std::endl;
}
```

Assuming `n` is the length of the input string and `m` the length of the positions vector, this performs:

`O(n + m) [Allocation] + O(n + m) [Copy] = O(n + m) [Total]`.

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for an in-place version. (Sorry, that was edited out from my original question.)